# Unexpected mongodb update blocked

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm performing query and update operations to a sharded mongo cluster (5 shards) and have come across a rather unusual problem (that I even struggle to describe clearly). This is the application setup:

- Mongo v3.0.12
- Java 8 (Standalone JVM)
- Morphia v1.3.2

Typical background load looks like this on the primary shard (using mongostat):

```
insert query update delete getmore command % dirty % used flushes vsize   res qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn set repl     time
     4  3120    785     *0     172   577|0     0.9   80.7       0 72.7G 40.9G   0|1   2|7    2m   163m 3420 rs0  PRI 15:46:29
     4  2324    475     *0     129   417|0     1.3   80.9       0 72.7G 40.9G   0|0   3|2    1m   124m 3420 rs0  PRI 15:46:30
     1  2503    425     *0     121   290|0     1.4   81.0       0 72.7G 40.9G   0|1   1|6    1m   114m 3420 rs0  PRI 15:46:31
     4  2322    469     *0     194   371|0     1.6   81.1       0 72.7G 40.9G   0|2   1|1    1m    86m 3420 rs0  PRI 15:46:32
     4  3349    435     *0     194   443|0     1.8   81.2       0 72.7G 40.9G   0|0   1|1    2m    83m 3420 rs0  PRI 15:46:33
     2  3071    474     *0     159   338|0     2.2   81.6       0 72.7G 40.9G   0|0   1|0    1m    87m 3420 rs0  PRI 15:46:34
     2  2661    394     *0     119   239|0     2.3   81.6       0 72.7G 40.9G   0|0   1|8  925k    81m 3420 rs0  PRI 15:46:35
```

Connections to primary shard:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.serverStatus().connections
{
        "current" : 3388,
        "available" : 47812,
        "totalCreated" : NumberLong(338643)
}
```

RS0 Resource stats:

[image: AWS System stats]

Hopefully that sets the scene. I then have two application servers that interact with the same DB but different collections:

- Application server A performs queries and updates to collection 1
- Application server B performs queries and updates to collection 2

I have recently added a new $set update operation to application server B, and it appears to have had the unfortunate side effect of significantly decreasing update performance on application server A (such that operations previously taking < 1 second are now timing at at ~60 seconds).

I believe this is the case as the newrelic CPU profiling, of application server A, is producing the following results while the set operation is running on application server B:

[image: Performance of update with SET operation]

And the same node in the profiler WITHOUT the set operation running on application server B:

[image: Performance of update without SET operation]

I note from these that during the new SET operation (on application server B) the mongo update operations (on application server A) are consuming ~25% of the total CPU time. Whilst the SET operation is not running the equivalent operations are only consuming ~5%.

My initial assumption had been that I'm hitting some kind of performance bottleneck on the mongo cluster. I have considered various causes:

Here is the mongostat output from RS0, whilst the SET operation is running on application server B:

```
insert query update delete getmore command % dirty % used flushes vsize   res qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn set repl     time
    *0  1405      1     *0      19   132|0     0.0   80.0       0 72.1G 40.9G   0|0   1|0  153k    11m 3419 rs0  PRI 15:46:08
    *0  1340     *0     *0      18   121|0     0.0   80.0       0 72.1G 40.9G   0|0   1|0  144k     7m 3419 rs0  PRI 15:46:09
    *0  1677     *0     *0      27   263|0     0.0   80.1       0 72.1G 40.9G   0|0   1|0  230k     9m 3419 rs0  PRI 15:46:10
    *0  1415      4     *0      35   198|0     0.0   80.0       0 72.1G 40.9G   0|0   1|0  183k     9m 3419 rs0  PRI 15:46:11
    *0  1350     *0     *0      17   123|0     0.0   80.0       0 72.1G 40.9G   0|0   1|0  143k    14m 3419 rs0  PRI 15:46:12
    *0  1036     *0     *0      21   141|0     0.0   80.0       0 72.1G 40.9G   0|0   1|0  130k     9m 3419 rs0  PRI 15:46:13
     1  1099     *0     *0      20   139|0     0.0   80.0       0 72.1G 40.9G   0|0   2|0  132k     8m 3419 rs0  PRI 15:46:14
```

I note the significant drop of in load. The AWS system metrics show a similar picture, a drop in CPU load & network IN/OUT.

Is it the number of connections into the node during the SET operation:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.serverStatus().connections
{
        "current" : 3419,
        "available" : 47781,
        "totalCreated" : NumberLong(338788)
}
```

Yes, there is an increase in the number of connections but not to a point where I believe it's the issue.

I then considered perhaps the SET operations might be slow so I enabled db profiling with a slowMS threshold of 2 seconds. During the period of the SET operation the slow query log only gained a single entry (which is due to a known slow operation on application server A), so no help there either.

I then looked to the performance of the journal volume, which is configured to use instance SSD store, using iostat:

```
iostat -x 5 -t
```

This likewise shows a similar picture as mongostat, i.e. the load appears to decrease when I see the slow down/blocking update on application server A, whilst the SET operation is running is running on application server B.

Unfortunately that's where I ran out of ideas and debugging thoughts. I would very much appreciate further help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Further investigations will consider replication lag (I'm using MAJORITY write concern).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the cause of this problem was:

- The use of majority write concern would block any other DB operations going to the same mongo cluster if replicas started to lag.
- The cause of the lag was our use of $push, which was creating hot spots in the oplog for specific shards, please see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9784 for more information.